# I'm trying to figure out if canon MF743cdw will work with ubuntu?

Tags: printing, canon

Is there a list of supported (tested)  printers somewhere ? Vaguely I thought I found a table somewhere that showed what feature worked with what printers but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are looking for the list of printers that is at [OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Canon)

The MF743cdw is not listed, but the MFxxx series of printers is under the 'paperweight' or 'mostly' supported sections of the table.  Canon itself does not seem to produce a linux driver for this printer.

Comment: bur like the HP range, a 'near' alternative in the range often works - maybe not with all the bells and whistles - but enough to get you by.

Comment: There is a better list i found somewhere of the models that were supported because it included stuff like MF733/MF731 which is not on that list.

Answer (score 0):

Update from 2020: [Their support portal](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/color-laser/color-imageclass-mf743cdw) has a driver download for Linux. Worked OOTB for me on customized Debian Testing; the installer claims to support "Fedora/Ubuntu/CentOS 7.6/Debian 8.11/Debian 9.8 or later".